# Denoise makes Image pixalated in Cycles

Tags: rendering, denoise

Hi I wanted to render an image in Cycles and I enabled denoising to remove the noise from the image. But now my image is always pixelated/blurred. Does anyone know what this could be or what settings I need to make? I use Blender 3.4.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 0.1 is a very high noise threshold for this material, try lowering it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help :(

Comment: also your max samples are 64, try at least 1024